# heatmap in excel 2007

Tags: excel, heatmap

I have some distances in Excel in the following format

[image]

I need to create a heatmap in Excel or in any other tool, so that I would be able to differentiate the values from each of the data.

Comment: Here is my simple solution: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54522/excel-heatmap-data-visualization-whitout-add-ins 

lmorin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also apply conditional formatting to your table. Just select one of the preset "Color Scales" rules. This won't create your heat map as a graphic, but rather it will be built into the cells in your worksheet.  See [my answer](https://superuser.com/questions/337303/plot-2d-graph-in-excel/337432#337432) to a previous question on SuperUser. You can avoid all the data transformation steps I describe there because your data is already in the right form to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Heat Maps in Excel using **Surface Charts**.

You can find some info on:

- [How to Create a Heat Map in Excel – Zimbio](https://web.archive.org/web/20120630144058/http://www.zimbio.com/Microsoft+Excel/articles/69/How+Create+Heat+Map+Excel)
- [How to Create a Heat Map in Excel](https://web.archive.org/web/20160422023433/http://how.best-free-information.com/2009/04/how-to-create-a-heat-map-in-excel/)

(Both of these use VBA.)